# Swift delete plist

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I use `NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(Any, toFile: String)` function to store object array in the plist of ios.

Each time I call this function, the new data is added to the plist file rather than override the old data.

My thought is to delete old plist file and write data to a new created plist of the same name.

But I don not know how to delete plist file with swift. Hope someone can help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you're writing the object you want? Maybe you have duplicates in your array. Try logging it. archiveRootObject should override the old file.

Comment: Sorry but your assumption is incorrect. `NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject` will not append to a file. It will overwrite any existing file.

Comment: Hey, guys!  Thanks for your help!  The problems is as DrummerB said, I duplicated data in my array!

Answer (score 3):

To delete a file from the system:

```
do {
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pathToPlist) {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: pathToPlist)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

A word of wanting: you can't delete a file from your bundle.